# Why is this Mathematica function definition returning an error?

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, definition, mathematica-8, wolfram-language

I am trying to put in a rather large function into mathematica:
 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXLsT.png)

I want to get it in so I can compute the global maxima, but I keep getting an error when I try and define the function. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Also, U(C) is U(C) not U(N) because it is a Kuhn Tucker reduction of an earlier equation, but the function should be a function of n in mathematica as that is all that will be allowed to vary.

All other variables are fixed values.

```
In[1]:= f(n) :=
        ((A*n^a)^(1/s) + 
        c*(B*(a*c*(B/A)^(1/s)*n^(1 - (a/s)))^(-(a*s)/(a - s)))^(1/s))^s +
        b*log (1 - n - ((a*c*(B/A)^(1/s)*n^(1 - (a/s)))^(-(a*s)/(a - s))))

        SetDelayed::write: Tag Times in f n is Protected. >>
Out[1]= $Failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `f[n_]:=` (`n` with an underscore `_`) when declaring the function, and not `f(n):=`

Comment: upcase L and square brackets on `Log[]` as well